# Is partitioning beneficial if create all the partitions in Primary File group only in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, partitioning, partition

I am new to SQL Server. I am trying to implement partitioning. But I have a question: is it necessary to have different partition groups?

Or what If I have only one partition group "PRIMARY" which is the default one? And in the partition schema, I specify the primary file group only.

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [Date] 
AS PARTITION [PF_FMvnt_Valuation_Date_SID] 
TO ([PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], 
    [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], 
    [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], 
    [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY])
GO

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [Date](bigint) 
AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (20170228, 20170331, 20170430, 
                          20170531, 20170630, 20170731, 
                          20170831, 20170930, 20171031, 
                          20171130, 20171231, 20180131, 
                          this, 28)
```

By implementing this, I am getting 12 partitions and data is getting populated to respective partitions.

But will this improve performance in terms of parallelism?

Sorry if you find this question too naive.

Comment: A File Group is not a facet of partitioning itself. Partitioning requires one or more file groups(the table has to live somewhere(s)). I would suggest that you post your question over at https://dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you partition for two reasons. To be able to drop and or add lots of data in one gulp or to improve performance. An organization may want to keep six weeks of current data in a very large table. Every weekend they may drop the oldest partition and create a new one for the new week's worth of data. Because this is mostly done as metadata changes a partition's worth of data (which could be 10-20 GB of data) can be dropped and/or added in seconds.

A second reason is to have the data on separate physical volumes. So if you are searching for a particular week only the data for that week is searched. If you have the entire table on one  volume (hence on one drive or set of drives) you won't get much of a performance improvement on searches but you may find adding and or dropping partitions is very fast.