# Table Partitioning to avoid locks

Tags: sql-server, database-partitioning

**TLDR**; I'm trying to partition a table such that each partition can be operated on without locking the others, but it's not working.

**Background**: I'm creating a data pipeline process that exports data from a central corporate database to a SQL Server DB, where it can be used for analytics. I need to export the full table each day (currently deleting the old one, archiving comes later) and it can be almost 10GB.

To make it fast enough to be usable, I break the table up into 15 chunks based on a "plan" column. This is done in the data pipeline so each of the 15 possible values in the "plan" column is treated independently; each plan chunk is pulled from the corporate DB, after which old data for that chunk is deleted in the SQL Server table and the new data is uploaded.

The problem is, doing this in 15 chunks means all the processes block one another. Everything has to wait on everything else, making it all go VERY slow in the end, and often fail due to timeouts.

To address this I've:

1. Created 16 SQL Server filegroups for the table in
2. Added a file to each filegroup
3. Partitioned the table on the plan column (the boundary for each filegroup is the name of one plan)

According to [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285595/is-partitioning-beneficial-if-create-all-the-partitions-in-primary-file-group-on) this should allow me to "drop or add lots of data in one gulp".

This doesn't seem to be helping though; I still get blocks.

So **two questions**:

1. Is it possible to partition such that each partition can be dealt with without blocking the others? If so, how?
2. Do I have to rerun the partition job each day? The various tutorials I've found about partitioning seem to sometimes imply so; it's unclear to me if the DB maintains the partition automatically or not.

**Alternative** I've also considered breaking the destination table up into 15 tables, and trying to recombine them with a view. Would that be better? Worse?

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you mean by "I break the table up into 15 chunks based on a "plan" column", pulling each chunk and process them, and how this ends up with "all the processes bolcking each other".  Could you give us a simplified example (like with 3 or 4 chunks instead of 15)?

Comment: Are you getting blocking because of table level lock escalation? You need to set `LOCK_ESCALATION = AUTO` to allow partition level lock escalation. This is not the default

Comment: @MartinSmith, I'd just discovered that! I switched it and am testing now to see if that's the issue. If it is I'll comment again to ask you to post this as an answer so I can mark it as correct. Hope to follow up soon.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, I edited to try and clarify. Basically my ETL process performs the check/delete/upload process for each value of plan independently. E.g. Plan A has all those queries run for it separate from Plan B. This allows me to have parallelism and load the data MUCH faster than if I did it all at once (which would also hit memory and space limits). That clearer?

Comment: Consider using partition switching: load data into an empty staging table with the exact same indexes, then do a fast switch in to the main table

Comment: @MartinSmith, I think your comment was the correct one. You want to post a link related to changing that setting as an answer and I'll mark it correct?

Comment: Also there is no need for multiple filegroups in this scenario.  You can have all the partitions in a single filegroup, and you don't need to create a bunch of extra files.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, does this mean I don't need new filegroups and files at all? i.e. partitioning in the base filegroup & file would be enough? Or that I could create multiple files in a single filegroup, partition that, and that would be enough?

Comment: You can put all the partitions on the Primary filegroup with a single file if you want.  Adding files and filegroups is neither required or helpful here.  If all the files are on the same volume, the performance will be exactly the same.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, thanks, VERY good to know! That makes life much simpler!

Comment: @Charlieface, note, question for you below the answer related to your comment above. Not sure the tagging there worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered similar issues in the past where concurrent workers are processing rows in a single physical partition each and different partitions but still blocking each other.

One reason this can happen is if one of the workers manages to escalate their lock to table level. You would need to examine the waiting tasks during a period of blocking to see if this applies to you.

SQL Server does support lock escalation to partition level but this is not the default (as can cause greater probability of deadlocks for some scenarios).

To enable this option you need to set `LOCK_ESCALATION = AUTO`.

If the work you are doing is replacing all the rows in the partition then you should consider [Charlieface's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface) comment and doing this in a new empty table per partition and using `TRUNCATE TABLE ... WITH (PARTITIONS ())` or `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH` to clear the old data and `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH` to bring in the new data (both should generally be very quick operations). This would mean the inserts are truly independent, and this pattern may well be more beneficial w.r.t. minimal logging for the insert.

Comment: Thanks so much!

For others who follow, I would also note that https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/246836/deadlock-on-partitioned-table was a nice summary (in the question) of the steps needed to set up much of this, though I think the above goes beyond that as well. Sharing because the link was helpful to me, for others who land here.

Comment: @Charlieface, if I do partition switching, would I need a separate staging table for each of the 15 partitions if I wanted to so them concurrently? Is there a guide you know of for setting that up?

Comment: @T.Shaffner Not necessarily, you can either switch a whole table or a partitioned table, but if partitioned they must be partitioned the same way. There are a number opf other restrictions, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191160(v=sql.105)

Comment: The " new empty table per partition" was when you were planning on having a partition per file group. The staging table needs to be on the right filegroup for that. But if you've abandoned that you just need as many staging tables as needed to work in parallel

Comment: @MartinSmith, thanks, that's helpful to know. After research though, it seems like I'd need to do a lot of this with manually hardcoded boundaries. I'm trying to make this robust enough to account for data content changes without data pipeline code updates though, and the partition switching seems to make that MUCH more complex (in particular, I'd need to know the name of the boundary of the partition when switching a new one in). For the moment I think that complexity is a bridge too far.

Comment: I got a little different behavior, even if I've create a clustered partitioned table when I update a single record on partition #3 I obtained a temporary:  IndId=*0* type=*TAB* resource=null Mode=IX Status=GRANT 

and as a result a *WAIT* in  ALTER TABLE Lst_xxxxx SWITCH PARTITION 13 TO Lst_xxxxx_Shadow PARTITION  13;

but the table is clustered not heap IndID=0 seems misbehaving

Comment: update the  ALTER TABLE Lst_xxxxx SWITCH PARTITION is requesting a **Sch-M** Schema Modification

Comment: @DiegoScaravaggi - did you set `LOCK_ESCALATION = AUTO`? From what I remember at least in the `TRUNCATE` case it doesn't request a SCH-M on the whole object then. But it is a while since I looked at this so can't remember the gory details

Comment: @MartinSmith yes LOCK_ESCALATION = AUTO, I'm running streaming ETL ingestion on the __latest__ partition, I think we can add an **optimistic** logic for having a chance in __low pressure__ weekly hours 
now I've already added try/error
`WITH (WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY (MAX_DURATION = 5 MINUTES,ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = SELF))`